# gstreamer pipeline cannot put tags into m4a file

Tags: gstreamer, gst-launch

this is my pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location="/home/mango/Desktop/gst-test/input.mp3" name=src \
! decodebin \
! audioconvert \
! faac \
! mp4mux \
! filesink location="/home/mango/Desktop/gst-test/output.m4a" \
```

But on 2 up-to-date manjaro installations and 1 outdated xubuntu installation it gives me this "input buffer disappeared" error, so I guess something is wrong with that pipeline. Using avenc_aac instead of faac gives the same error.

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
0:00:00.025318250  8742 0x5581248e7f30 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3600:gst_base_src_start_complete:<src> pad not activated yet
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
0:00:00.042874308  8742 0x7f4e340779e0 FIXME               basesink gstbasesink.c:3246:gst_base_sink_default_event:<filesink0> stream-start event without group-id. Consider implementing group-id handling in the upstream elements
0:00:00.042898718  8742 0x7f4e340779e0 WARN                   qtmux gstqtmux.c:2981:gst_qt_mux_start_file:<mp4mux0> Robust muxing requires reserved-moov-update-period to be set
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
0:00:00.046081143  8742 0x7f4e340779e0 WARN                   libav gstavauddec.c:628:gst_ffmpegauddec_drain:<avdec_mp3-0> send packet failed, could not drain decoder
0:00:00.046300293  8742 0x7f4e340779e0 WARN            audioencoder gstaudioencoder.c:965:gst_audio_encoder_finish_frame:<faac0> Can't copy metadata because input buffer disappeared
Got EOS from element "pipeline0".
Execution ended after 0:00:00.003472255
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

there aren't any tags in the output file

However,

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location="/home/mango/Desktop/gst-test/input.mp3" name=src \
! decodebin \
! audioconvert \
! flacenc \
! filesink location="/home/mango/Desktop/gst-test/output.flac" \
```

works fine and I get a .flac file with tags.

How can I fix the first pipeline so that there are tags in output.m4a?

GStreamer 1.16.2

Answer (score 0):

see https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-good/-/issues/759

- "Can't copy metadata because input buffer disappeared" is not related to tags and possibly fixed in the current gstreamer master
- ffprobe shows the tags, while mediainfo-gui and ex falso (and quod libet which is both the same project or something) don't